# .aspx redirect to Umbraco 5 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, asp.net-mvc-3-areas, umbraco5

I have custom Area in my Umbraco 5 web application named "en", i want to redirect my old links(prior to Umbraco 5 on other sites) to new ones automatically,
in my Area Registeration File i have mapped the new Route as

```
context.MapRoute(
             "en_Home",
            "en/{url}.aspx",
            new { action = "HomeRedirection", controller = "Redirection"}
            );
```

but it gives me "The resource cannot be found", if i remove the .aspx Bit it works, i created a simple mvc3 application to test my code there and it all worked fine with ".aspx" links redirecting normally with the code above, i don't know what i am doing wrong, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Sher